# Bridging header not found when creating app extension

Tags: swift2, ios-app-extension, bridging-header

Trying to create a document provider app extension for my app, returns me this error when I try to run the project after creating the app extension (just creating it not adding anything else) :

> error: bridging header '/myPath/test-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist

Apparently the app extension is not searching at the right path, the bridging header is in the folder with all the classes and the app extension is looking for it at the root of the project.
Any fix?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a problem with the file path you've provided.

By default Xcode will look for your bridging header file from the directory where you can find your xcodeProj file.

In XCode, go to your Project's *Building Settings* and search for *Code Generation*.  Under *Swift Compiler - Code Generation*, verify the path you've supplied for your bridging header file.